# ¿Cómo acceder al id de varios arreglos que estan dentro de otro arreglo de forma dinámica?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#312 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "Gotze"

  }
  1 => {#321 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "Ariel"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende como lo quieras hacer, asumiendo que sean arrays, puedes usar el helper `array_pluck()` para obtener un arreglo con solo los id:

```
$array1 = [
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'gotze'], 
    ['id' => 3,'name' => 'ariel']
];
array_pluck($array1, 'id');
```

el resultado sería:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
]
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-pluck

Si necesitas accederlos uno por uno, podrías utilizar el típico foreach:

```
foreach ($array1 as $arr) {

    echo $arr['id'];

}
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio tu respuesta con array_pluck, lo que pasa es que necesitos todos esos id para luego utilizarlos en otra consulta. Lo siguiente que necesito es que juntar todos esos id en una sola variable.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás usando un arreglo de objetos, no un arreglo de arreglos. Podrías hacer lo siguiente (sin dependencias, con PHP):

```
$out = array_reduce($in, function($carry, item) {
    $carry[] = $item->id;

    return $Carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: desconozco porque tuviste un -1, que igual fue retirado. pero por favor, mira los siguientes links [tour], [ask], [answer]. Bienvenido!

Comment: @gbianchi Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias!

Comment: como funciona array_reduce?